# Merging duplicates and summing field in a multidimensional collection in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I've inherited a Laravel 5.4 project. Upgrading isn't an option and neither is a large scale rewrite so I'm stuck with what I've got. I have an eloquent collection that looks as follows when fetched from the database and simplified:

**`$orders`**

```
[
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 3,
    "qty": 2,
    "hotlist": null
  },
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 4,
    "qty": 5,
    "hotlist": null
  },
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 3,
    "qty": 1,
    "hotlist": true
  },
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 3,
    "qty": 1,
    "hotlist": null
  },
]
```

There are obviously more than 1 item but this will show what I'm more or less working with and what I need to accomplish. I'm attempting to give a report of items. If they are the same item, in the same status, and not on the hotlist they should be 1 line item with the total quantity. Using the above example I need an output like this example:

```
[
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 3,
    "qty": 3,
    "hotlist": null
  },
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 4,
    "qty": 5,
    "hotlist": null
  },
  {
    "item": Item 1,
    "status": 3,
    "qty": 1,
    "hotlist": true
  },
]
```

The only change is is the quantity of the first and last item have been summed and the duplicate item removed. I've come close using the following code:

```
$orders->groupBy('item')->flatMap(function ($items) {
  $quantity = $items->sum('qty');
  return $items->map(function ($item) use ($quantity) {
     $item->qty = $quantity;
     return $item;
  });
});
```

Obviously however it only takes into account the item name is the same then sums it, but I also need to verify the list and status. I've been banging my head against the wall with this one so I feel like it's got to be something simple I'm overlooking. Hopefully somebody can see what I'm missing.

Comment: Just to check, is $orders the array in the first code snippet? aka the array of items

Comment: Correct. I'll edit the description to clear that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very performant, but tentatively:

```php
// make it a collection so we can use the helper methods
$collection = collect([]); 

$orders->each(function ($item) use ($collection) {
   $target = $collection->where('item', $item->item)
                        ->where('hotlist', $item->hotlist)
                        ->where('status', $item->status);
   if ($target->count() == 0) 
      $collection->push($item); // If it hasn't been added, add it to the collection
   else
      $target->first()->qty += $item->qty;
});

dd($collection); // double check
```

Comment: I think there's some confusion. The `$orders` variable is already an eloquent collection. It's fetched as such: `$orders = Note::where('supplier_id', Auth::user()->supplier_id)->whereIn('status_id', [3, 4])->with('hotlist')->with('status')->get(['id', 'item', 'qty', 'status_id']);`

Comment: @RedElement yeap, ik! my point is to create a new Collection (`$collection`), add/sum the qty, and return that new Collection in your controller function. Leave `$orders` alone - don't return it. If it's a requirement to NOT create new variables,t then I'll think of something else.

Comment: Yeah I finally saw what you were doing after the comment. I don't care about the new variable. However it didn't work, for some reason `$target->count()` always equals 0.

Comment: Ok, this has got me most of the way there. I had to change `$orders->each(function ($item) use ($arr) {` to `$orders->each(function ($item) use ($collection) {` and correct a spelling mistake I made. It is getting rid of the duplicates as it should, but the qty is not updating.

Comment: Omg I'm so sorry, `$collection` was actually `$arr` but I changed it to be more semantic, and forgot to change that part. Are some of your qty null? Because null will be treated as zero. Both the quantity and duplicates work fine on my side tho - maybe you could post some more data so that I can test it too?

Comment: I've just gone through all the records and `qty` has to be a non 0 value and all are outputting as such. Negative integers are also not possible. It seems like it is summing the value, but it's doing it with itself. For example, I have a duplicate with `qty => 1` and `qty => 2`. It is summing a total, but I'm just getting 2 because it is adding 1+1.

Comment: It was a problem with my collection. 1 errant row was throwing the whole thing off.